# How to wrap ng-content elements separately?

Tags: angular

I want to wrap every `ng-content` element seperately with html that's controlled by the parent.

Example:

```
<parent-component>
    <span>Child 1</span>
    <span>Child 2</span>
    <span>Child 3</span>
</parent-component>
```

Desired result:

```
<parent-component>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="item">
                <span>Child 1</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="item">
                <span>Child 2</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="item">
                <span>Child 3</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</parent-component>
```

Does anyone have a clue how to handle this?

Comment: I don't really get it - why don't you create the result HTML structure and only reference the children in the leaf span-s?

Comment: This is a simplified example, the why is pretty complex. I just want to be able to wrap every child of a component.

Comment: @tzi if the why is complex, then explain the issue. This can be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), and we can probably find other ways to resolve your issue.

Comment: I want my component to handle a grid space repartitions with flexbox. But flexbox interfere with child display mode. It would more maintainable for me to have my component really isolated so the flexible element would be in the parent. The parent will be the responsible of the size and position, the child will be fluid. I'm curisous, because it's quite easy to do it in VueJs and React. I'm curious it doesn't exist in Angular

Comment: Please go through the link https://medium.freecodecamp.org/everything-you-need-to-know-about-ng-template-ng-content-ng-container-and-ngtemplateoutlet-4b7b51223691