# How to select the nth child with ng-content in angular

Tags: angular

I want to be able to select the children by their position. For example:

```js
<ul>
  <li>
    <ng-content select=":nth-child(1)"></ng-content>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ng-content select=":nth-child(2)"></ng-content>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: you can use `$index`

Comment: what you mean by 'select'? Click it? Highlight it?

Comment: I mean select for "Angular Content Projection". You can find information about it here: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/projection.html

Comment: please can you elaborate what you are trying to achieve? We can help you better if we can understand your use case.

Comment: I try to wrap every children with its own wrapper. This is essential for me but I do not find any solution for nos (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54809783/how-to-wrap-ng-content-elements-separately). I can find the number of children with a `@ContentChildren`, but it seems impossible to render a QueryChild. So a solution could be to make a loop with the length of my children, and select the `ng-content` by their position

Answer (score -1):

Use structural directive ngFor and then work with index

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  {{i}} {{item}}
</li>
```

Comment: I understand that part. I don't know how to use the index to filter the content projection with the child position